# PHP get cookie by value

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I've recently been trying to make this little modification on my website. Basically logged in users can add games to their favorite, and not logged in visitors will be directed to the register page.

Although I thought I could try and work on my PHP a little bit and enable visitors to add games to their favorites too. (Games being flash games)

So I made this JS script that will allow the user to click on an image, this one checks if the cookie already exists, if not it will add it, and if it does exist, it will remove the cookie (an image changes from "Add to favorites" to "Remove from favorites"

Since there can be many different favorited games, I cannot use a simple cookie name, so I set it up like this: xx1200=set (so there is 2 x's, then the game id which makes the cookie title, and then the "set" being the cookie value. All the favorited games will have the same value, but different names, being their ID with xx in front.

Now to print the cookies on another page, displaying their favorited games, I added PHP on a page so basically get the cookie, but there resides my problem: how to get a cookie name by its value (normally you will print `$_COOKIE["set"];` but now my cookie name changes.

I use `print_r($_COOKIE);` to print the whole cookie, and I see my `[zz800] => set` in the array, but I cannot figure out how to get the ID (being 800 in the example above) to then get the game(s) corresponding to the given ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks you:)

#### Update:

This is the code I have for now, been working on and off for the last couple hours, right now it does work alright, I didnt add the PHP tho, just the javascript.

My only problem is when I try to delete 1 entry, it will delete the whole cookie, so I cannot seem to find where to fix that.
Another issue would be to get the IDs out of the array, if anybody could help me there, it would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$globalCookie = '629';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Document sans titre</title>
<script>
function createCookie(value)
{
 if(document.cookie.search(value)==-1){
  if(document.cookie.indexOf('games') == -1) {
  document.cookie = 'games' + '=' + ',' + value + '; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2011 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';
  } else {
  var deagle = document.cookie;
  document.cookie = deagle + ',' + value + '; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2011 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';
  } 
 } else {
  // Removes the cookie (making the clear cookie problem most probably
  document.cookie = 'games' + '=' +escape( value ) + '; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2001 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var globalCookie = <?=$globalCookie?>;
</script>
<?php
$stuff = $_COOKIE["games"];
$game = $globalCookie;
$pos = strpos($stuff, $game);

if ($pos === false) { ?>
   <a href='javascript:;'><img id="mygame1" src='images/add_mygames.gif' border="0" onClick="createCookie(globalCookie); (this.src=='images/add_mygames.gif')?(this.src='images/remove_mygames.gif'):(this.src='images/add_mygames.gif');"></a>
<? 
} else { ?>
   <a href='javascript:;'><img id="mygame1" src='images/remove_mygames.gif' border="0" onClick="createCookie(globalCookie); (this.src=='images/remove_mygames.gif')?(this.src='images/add_mygames.gif'):(this.src='images/remove_mygames.gif');"></a>
    
<?
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I use the $globalCookie as a replacement for my games IDs for now.

Thanks again for any help!

Also the cookie that the above makes looks like:

```
games=,621,256,637,57354
```

Only way I find to work with the explode(), since if the comma is after the number, it will not count the first one

Comment: no its for visitors, i already have a different system using my database for users

Comment: Using strpos to search data ini comma delimitted string is a bad idea. For example: games=,621,256,637,57354 and you'll find '21' will have a result while you know it should result false. Solution: use array_search (explode with comma first) or use PCRE.

Answer (score 3):

### Change Tactics

You should store the cookie information differently, as a comma-separated list of game ids like this:

```
games=123,345,641
```

You could use something like this to parse & access the data:

```
$games = explode(',', $_COOKIE['games'];

foreach( $games as $game_id ){
    echo $game_id;
}
```

Which gives you an array of game ids that the user has favourited.

### Adding / Removing

Since you'll be using only one cookie to store favourited games, as a user favourites / unfavourites games, you'll need to write code to implement the following (in Javascript):

When a user favourites / unfavourites a game

- open the current favourite games cookie
- append / remove the relevant id ( hint: use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to split the cookie into a Javascript array for the latter action )
- re-sets the cookie with the new game id string

### Why?

For keyed values, one really needs a key that is known. Anything else is rather pointless. In your problem you have information that you want to store in a cookie, that can consist of any number of values. Much better to store / send these values as a delimited list than by trying to jimmy each value into a cookie as a key. Luckily your data (numeric ids) lends itself well to this method.

Comment: the user add the games one by one, so basically it's a new cookie create everytime he/she adds a game to their favorites, so I cant see how I would make a list, in example when the user adds the game ID '123' it will make the cookie 123=set for example, and then when he favorites '345' it will make another cookie. let me know if i catch it wrong, & thanks alot for the reply

Comment: Pretty easy to do actually, what you can do is exactly what he suggested, if the user adds a new game, grab the current $_COOKIE['games'] array, and add a new value.

So if a user favorites a game, you could do something like:
if(isset($_COOKIE['games'])) {
$_COOKIE['games'] .= ",$newid";
} else {
$_COOKIE['games'] = "$newid";
}
To allow you to either create the cookie, with the values you want, or you can just append new values.  Well, if I could get my formatting right, but the code example is about the same.

Comment: so basically a "games" cookie, storing all the game ID's. how will I manage to open up the cookie and append a new value to it tho? Edit: alright i get what you posted there, altho i make my cookies with javascript and print them thru php

Comment: alright thanks alot for this, ill get to work right away now having this in mind - many thanks again!

Comment: +1 for not taking question literally but proposing a better solution, which is extremely rare behavior here

Comment: @Alex glad I could help! This solution will result in less headaches for you. @TheCol. Sir! Thankyou Sir! I wish only that said behaviour was the norm, sir!

Comment: I think it's better trick. You could use JSON format when cookie data more complex than this as json's parsers are available almost in every language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan the cookies and get the Game ID you could try:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
echo("Game ID: ".substr($key,3)." - Status: ".$value);
}
```

which in the example above should output "Game ID: 800 - Status: set"

Answer (score 0):

Use array_keys on second argument. It's similiar to array_search except it returns an array match the value given in the second argument while array_search always return the first matching only.

```
<?
//example data
$_COOKIE = array(
    'zz800' => 'set',
    'zz801' => 'set',
    'zz802' => 'set',
    'yz800' => 'test'
);

print_r(array_keys($_COOKIE, 'set'));
//result
array('zz800', 'zz801', 'zz802');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need array search if you want this to work how you have written it.

```
var_dump( array_search('set', $_COOKIE) );
```

I think its quite a bad idea to implement it like this though to be honest!

Comment: how would you do it then? i couldnt find a better way than that (well for visitors anyways, it's another system for the actual users)